# Linux export command in python - os.system('export ... ') - syntax error

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a python script which would help me set environment variables in linux.

I am trying to do:

```
export ARMROOT=/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106
export ARMLIB=$ARMROOT/lib
export ARMINCLUDE=$ARMROOT/include
```

by using the following lines:

```
import os
os.system('export ARMROOT=/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106')
os.environ.get['ARMROOT']
os.system('export ARMLIB=$ARMROOT/lib')
os.environ.get['ARMLIB']
os.system('export ARMINCLUDE=$ARMINCLUDE/inc`enter code here`lude')
os.environ.get['ARMINCLUDE']
```

I am not quite sure I completely understand the concept of os.environ or if I am doing this right.

Please let me know if there is any other way I should go about doing this.
I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set it directly:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['ARMROOT'] = '/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106'
>>> os.environ['ARMROOT']
'/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106'
```

if you use `os.system`, then the environment variable is only set for the duration of the `os.system` call is is lost immediately after that call returns:

```
>>> os.system('export ARMROOT=something_else')
0
>>> os.environ['ARMROOT']
'/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106'
```

Comment: I tried that too, I still get an error with this. 

  File "setenv.py", line 78
    os.environ['ARMROOT'] = '/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106',
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3281103 That line is perfectly valid.  That you get an error likely means that you have an error on one of the preceding lines, maybe a missing close quote or something.

Comment: Thanks but the preceding lines look fine to me as far as I can see. This is my block
 env_dict = {
  #print("**********************************LINUX ENVIRONMENT******************")
        os.environ['HEXAGON_ROOT'] : '/pkg/abc/software/hexagon/releases/tools',
        
        "ARMTOOLS"     : "ARMCT5.05",

  os.environ['ARMROOT'] = '/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106',
        #print os.environ["ARMROOT"]
  os.environ['ARMLIB']    = os.path.join('ARMROOT', 'lib'),
  os.environ['ARMINC']    = os.path.join('ARMROOT', 'include'),
  os.environ['ARMBIN']       = os.path.join('ARMROOT', 'bin')}

Comment: @user3281103 That is where the syntax error is.   Those lines are a dictionary definition, `env_dict = { key : value, ... }` but mixed in with the key:value pairs are some assignment statements, `os.environ['ARMROOT'] = '/pkg/abc/software/arm/RVDS/5.05bld106',`.  That is what is giving you the error.